# Invoke Html Button click with WebForm_DoPostBackOptions and WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a windows forms application with a form that has a webbrowser control on it. In the html body of the webbrowser control there is a button I am trying to invoke the click event html tag

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$FilterButton" class="MPPBtn" id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_FilterButton" 
onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$FilterButton", "", true, "", "", false, true))' type="button" value="Filter">
```

I already got the code to get the button and invoke the click event

```
   HtmlElement filterBtn = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_FilterButton");
   filterBtn.InvokeMember("Click");
```

My issue is that when invoking the click event thru code it doesn't behave the same way as it would if I clicked in a regular browser like chrome. I am thinking that might be because of the javascript:WebForm_DoPostbackoption

```
onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$FilterButton", "", true, "", "", false, true))'
```

I have already looked around and saw that I might have to invoke javascript:webform_dopostback but that doesn't really make sense bec I would think that once you get the button and invoke the click event then that would be taken care for you? But I tried adding invoking the script as so with no avail

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$FilterButton', '', true, '', '', false, true))");
```

Can someone explain what I am suppose to do or how to handle the WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these line of code

```
            HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
            IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
            element.text = "function Filter() { javascript: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('id of element', '', true, '', 'url', false, true)) }";
            head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
            webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("Filter");
```